# Como alterar a cor de um mat-button no Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Como se torna possível alterar a cor de um mat-button do angular? Estou utilizando o theme indigo-pink, e ele possui um accent rosa, não acho que combina, e gostaria de alterar para outra cor, mas no css não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isso possa ajudar:

CSS:

```
.mat-button.mat-blue {
   color: blue;
}

.mat-raised-button.mat-blue, .mat-flat-button.mat-blue{
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-button color="blue">Custom Blue Button</button>

<button mat-raised-button color="blue">Custom Blue Button</button>

<button mat-flat-button color="blue">Custom Blue Button</button>
```